# Firestore Flutter How to get a list all the documents and its data inside a collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working to get a list of all the documents inside a firestore collection. I want to display all details of all documents inside a collection.
My document tree is ask follows-

'groups' COLLECTION----->Documents w 'groupID' as reference------>'tasks' COLLECTION------>Documents w 'taskId' as reference.

Now I want to get all documents and its details inside 'tasks' collection for a particular groupID.

```
Future<MyTask> getCurrentTask(String groupId) async {
    MyTask retVal = MyTask();
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot _docSnapshot =
          await _firestore.collection("groups").document(groupId).collection("tasks").get();
      retVal.taskId = taskId;
      retVal.taskName = _docSnapshot.data['taskName'];
      retVal.dueTime = _docSnapshot.data['dueTime'];
      retVal.member =_docSnapshot.data['member'];
      retVal.completed = _docSnapshot.data['completed'];
  
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

I tried this but it doesnt work as "The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'."
How to get around this please?

Comment: So, looking at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference), it looks like there is no method get, but from this other [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying) it looks like you can make a Query first in order to get the data from the collection. I believe that this could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("groups").document(groupID).collection("task").snapshots().listen((event) {
  retVal = event.documents.map((e) => MyTask.fromJson(e.data)).toList();
});
```

I assume your MyTask model already have fromJson method so do it like that. And change your retVal to List: `List<MyTask> retVal = [];`. It will get all of your document and also listen whether there's change's on the collection.